# Postgresql: Even when I grant the owner role, I can't alter tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions, alter-table, role

I have a Postgres database with a schema named `foo` owned by a user also named `foo`, which also owns all of the tables in it.

While logged in as `foo`, I created a user `bar` and granted it everything `foo`:

```
grant foo to bar;
grant all on all tables in schema foo to bar;
grant all on all sequences in schema foo to bar;
```

Now, logged in as `bar`, I attempt to alter a table in the `foo` schema:

```
alter table foo.baz add column col1 varchar(1);
```

And I get the error:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of table baz
```

Why won't Postgres let `bar`, as a member of `foo`, alter one of `foo`'s tables? From [everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584640/postgresql-error-must-be-owner-of-relation-when-changing-a-owner-object) I've [read](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html), granting the role should do the trick.

Comment: Having the same privileges as the table owner is not the same as being the table owner.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `bar` has `NOINHERIT` set, which means that it doesn't automatically assume the privileges of roles granted to it.

I can fix this on a query-by-query basis by having `bar` first do

```
SET ROLE foo;
```

To fix it permanently, I can have `foo` (which also created `bar`) make bar inherit:

```
ALTER ROLE bar INHERIT;
```